# With the R package xlsx, is it possible to set na.strings when reading an Excel file?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, na

I'm reading in an Excel file using `read.xlsx`, and I would like to set na.strings as you can with `read.table`. Is this possible? It doesn't work to just add na.strings to the call like this:

```
Data <- read.xlsx("my file.xlsx", sheetName = "MyData", na.strings = "no info")
```

Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: You can do that with `gdata::read.xls`

Comment: use `readxl` package from @hadley  https://github.com/hadley/readxl

Comment: I found that readxl truncates decimals sometimes, so I'd prefer to avoid that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No this is not possible for the simple reason that `read.xlsx` doesn't take care of special missing values. But this can be a possible enhancement for `getCellvalue` function.

You can either replace missing values using something like :

```
 Data[Data=="no info"] <- NA
```

Or, transform your data to a csv and use `read.csv` , or as commented use another package that take care of missing values.

#### Edit use XLConnect package:

The more performant `XLConnect` package takes care of missing values using `setMissingValue` function. Here the equivalent code can be written as:

```
library("XLConnect")
wb <- loadWorkbook("my file.xlsx")
setMissingValue(wb, value = "no info")
readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "MyData")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do but you can easily use apply to do that after you have loaded the excel file:

```
Data <- data.frame(apply(Data,1:2,function(x) if( x %in% 'no info') return(NA) else return(x)))
```

Obviously where 'no info' you can have your own na.strings vector

Hope that helps!

Comment: I agree that you method is more compact and definitely works well, but first you had already answered that before I even saw the question and second this site is to provide answers so that people can see them and learn new ways of doing that. that's why the site let's you have more than 1 answer. But I agree your way is better than mine. +1 from me.

Comment: Of course you are welcome to add as many answer as you want. My answer is better not because is more concise or "compact", it is better because it is **vectorized**, you should avoid to use `apply` because internally it will transform your data.frame to a matrix of characters.

Comment: Cool. I agree with you. If one person can benefit from my answer and learn about apply and then use yours because it is vectorized I will be happy.