# How to deal with NA values when they appear nothing?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've a handy function for computing the number of observations and the relative proportion. It works fine, but sometimes when I read in Excel spreadsheets I got "NA" values as simply empty cells like "", causing R to not recognize as a NA value as in the following output. Which is not very interesting for producing  graphs.

```
> table(is.na(factor(BASE$Q008)))

FALSE 
  437 

> df
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

            Q008     n  prop
          (fctr) (int) (dbl)
1     Evangelical  172  0.39
2       Catholic   150  0.34
3         Other     51  0.12
4  Not religious    57  0.13
5    Protestant      6  0.01
6                    1  0.00
```

To bypass this, I need to recode the factor with: `recode(BASE$Q008, from="", to=NA)`. This gives the right test, but a category NA is also plotted in the graph, even when using `x=factor(Q008)` in ggplot2.

```
> table(is.na(as.character(BASE$Q008)))

FALSE  TRUE 
  436     1 

> df
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

            Q008     n  prop
          (fctr) (int) (dbl)
1     Evangelical  172  0.39
2       Catholic   150  0.34
3         Other     51  0.12
4  Not religious    57  0.13
5    Protestant      6  0.01
6           NA       1  0.00
```

Is there a better way of improving this snippet so to recognize NA values when they appear nothing? Also, not plotting them as a level?

```
mytable <- function(x, ...) x %>% 
group_by_(...) %>% 
summarise(n = n()) %>% 
mutate(prop = round(n/sum(n),2))
```

Comment: What are you using to read in your data?  If the function has an `na` argument, you should be able to tell the function what character sets to convert to `NA`.

Comment: I'm using `read.xlsx2` from `xlsx` package. The library `readxl` reads it correctly, with "" in the Excel as NA, but adds much more issues when trying to interpret the class of column.

Comment: It seems `read.xlsx2` doesn't have an argument to set the `na` string, but here's a similar question that gives some pointers on how to handle your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743036/with-the-r-package-xlsx-is-it-possible-to-set-na-strings-when-reading-an-excel

Comment: Why isn't just `df <- df[!is.na(as.character(df$$Q008)),]` or even something simpler not the solution here?

Comment: Maybe even `df <- df[df$$Q008=="",]` would do it.

Comment: Just to make things clear, is.na() doesn't work as I mentioned in my question; must be =="".